# Merge Rows in pandas dataframe having same string in a column

Tags: python, pandas, string, rows

I'm new to python.
I've 2 dataframes:

```
df1:         
         Col1  Col2  Col3  Col4
        0 A     A1   A2     0
        1 B     B1   B2     0
        2 C     C1   Nan    0
df2:
        Col1  Col2  Col3 Col4
       1 B    NaN   NaN   B3
       4 C    NaN   C2    C3
```

Expected Out:

```
    Col1  Col2  Col3 Col4
   0 A     A1    A2   0
   1 B     B1    B2   B3
   2 C     C1    C2   C3
```

tried pd.concat(), it merged both data frames having dublicate strings in columns.

want to merge two rows having same string value in 1st column.
Any help will be appreciated, Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`df.set_index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) with [`df.update`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.update.html) and [`df.reset_index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html):

```
In [1355]: df1 = df1.set_index('Col1')
In [1356]: df1.update(df2.set_index('Col1'))

In [1358]: df1.reset_index(inplace=True)

In [1359]: df1
Out[1359]: 
  Col1 Col2 Col3 Col4
0    A   A1   A2    0
1    B   B1   B2   B3
2    C   C1   C2   C3
```

Comment: partially working for me, actually used .explode() earlier to split series into rows. those new rows only 1st col is merged other cols shows old data. Any other way to achieve this?

Comment: Please share the exact code you are using in the question with the error. I've pasted the working code in my answer. No errors here.

Comment: Here's my code, [scorecard.ipynb](https://www.mediafire.com/file/lyjw6lk2pez7tid/scorecard.ipynb/file).
Some rows are not getting merged, Any help will be appreciated. Thank you bro :)